# Spring data rest and JPA, query by association

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, single-page-application

I'm trying to use "findBy" statement in JPA.
My entity class is:

```
@Entity
public class Visit {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
private Specialist specialist;

@ManyToOne
private Treatment treatment;

@ManyToOne
private Office office;
.
.
.
```

Here is repository:

```
public interface VisitRepository extends CrudRepository<Visit, Long>            {

@RestResource(rel="byOffice", path="byOffice")
List<Visit> findByOffice(@Param("office") Office office);

}
```

I'm trying to find all Visits where office id is something so i'm making the request:
http://localhost:8080/visits/search/byOffice?office=1

But the response is:

```
status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception":      "org.springframework.data.repository.support.QueryMethodParameterConversionException",
"message": "Failed to convert 1 into core.domain.Office!",
"path": "/visits/search/byOffice"
```

What should i do to make it work? Is it good approach?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: Can you try removing the annotation `RestResource(rel="byOffice", path="byOffice")`?

Comment: Doesn't work. It's just change the path of the resorce to default one ( /search/findByOffice )

Comment: "Failed to convert 1 into core.domain.Office!" you dont  set id you must to sent Office object

Comment: OK, can you give me an example ? What should i pass as json param ? Should i convert it in any way ? I've tried to find one in the internet, but i can't

Comment: I think change findByOffice to findById not try to find by office this a bit more difficult

Comment: for example this 
Visit findById(@Param("id") Long id);
http://localhost:8080/visits/search/byOffice?id=1

Comment: In the result of your example, there will be a visit with ID = 1 . I need to fetch all visits which have office ( basicly office_id ) = something

Comment: Id primary key for visit entity your visit table only one record include for id =1 not need fetch to all visits object

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few years late, but I'll leave this here should someone wander this way again.  (thanks to kakashi hatake for pointing out the error which I overlooked).

change the findBy method to this:

```
@RestResource(rel="byOffice", path="byOffice")
List<Visit> findByOffice_Id(@Param("officeId") long officeId);
```

and change the request to match:

`http://localhost:8080/visits/search/byOffice?officeId=1`

Answer (score 0):

Struggling to find a way for this either. It seems this is not possible with Spring Data's repository generation. What you can do, however, is having a repository for the other side of the association and use it this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/offices/1/visits
```